# Rotate directly towards a target at a constant speed

Tags: mathematics, javascript, rotation

I've written a program ([see on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billettg/sjeder3d/2/)) that rotates my player towards the mouse cursor at a constant speed. I've computed the angle to the point using the `Math.atan2` function, but when incrementing or decrementing the player's rotation towards that value, it does not always take the shortest path.

This image describes the logic I intend to evaluate:
[image]

The problem appears when you cross a specific angle, the player rotates the long way around to reach the cursor, instead of taking the shortest path. How can I always take the shortest path at a constant speed?

Many thanks.

Comment: I tried using a dot product of the player and mouse position but the player just seems to spin, argh.

`var dot = player.x*-mouse.y + player.y*mouse.x;if(dot > 0){
  player.r -= inc;
}else if(dot < 0){
 player.r += inc;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you did not account for the discontinuity in the arctangent function...

```
// Check if arctangent has crossed the discontinuity
if (delta < -Math.PI || (delta > 0 && delta < Math.PI)) {
```

And you are not reducing the player rotation into a canonical `-Pi <= x < Pi` range.

```
// Reduce player.r into the -PI thru PI range
player.r = (player.r + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

Additionally, to actually get a fixed rotation speed, you can not rely on the refresh rate of the screen. Instead you must either measure the clock each update, or use an interval timer.

```
setInterval(update, 1000 / 24); // run update at 24fps to achieve constant rate
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sjeder3d/8/

Comment: The fixed rotation speed is always achieved without using the `setInterval()` function. If the game slows down for some reason, the object is still rotating at a speed coherent with the game world logic.

Comment: As I've said, you could measure the clock at each update instead of using an interval timer, but it's more complicated. Such a simple fixed update was natural for this example. The question is about rotating at constant speed, not about synchronizing game logic.

Comment: Many thanks Mick for your advice and guidance despite my incoherent post! I'll get to implementing this in the logic and learning more about the calculations later.